# How to cluster a large text corpus (e.g. list of job titles) using Python or R?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have a text corpus - the list of job tiles extracted from the web. The list is pretty clean and stored as one column CSV file where titles are listed in rows.

I have tried approaches using TF-IDF and Affinity Propagation, but this runs into memory issues. I tried to do this using `word2vec` and then applying a clustering algorithm, but it's not showing decent results. What could be the most effective way to cluster the dataset of around 75k job titles?

Answer (score 1):

You can featurize the titles with word-level embeddings like `gensim.models.word2vec` and then use `sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN`. It's hard to give any more concrete advice without seeing the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to vectorize the text using tfidf or word2vec etc. Please see tfidf implementation below:
I am skipping the preprocessing part as it would vary depending on the problem statement.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')
text = df.text.values
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
vec_fit = tfidf.fit(text)
features = vec_fit.transform(text)
# now comes the clustering part, you can use KMeans, DBSCAN at your will
model = DBSCAN().fit(features)  # this might take ages as per size of the text and does not require to provide no. of clusters!!!
unseen_features = vec_fit.transform(unseen_text)
y_pred = model.predict(unseen_features)
```

There are evaluation techniques for clustering and available in sklean doc:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternatives can be a topic modeling, e.g. Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) model.

Minimal `R` example can look like:

```
library(topicmodels)
library(tidytext)
library(data.table)
library(tm)

# Reading Craigslist job titles
jobs <- fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/app-ask-craig/master/workflow/data/craigslistJobTitles.csv')
jobs[, doc_id := 1:.N]

# Building a text corpus
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(jobs[, .(doc_id, text = jobtitle)])),
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                         removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE,
                                         stemming = TRUE,
                                         wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))

# Let's set number of topics to be equal to number of categories and fit LDA model
n_topics <- length(unique(jobs[, category]))
lda <- LDA(dtm, k = n_topics, method = 'Gibbs', control = list(seed = 1234, iter = 1e4))

# Kind of confusion matrix to inspect relevance
docs <- setDT(tidy(lda, matrix = 'gamma'))[, document := as.numeric(document)]
docs <- docs[, .(topic = paste0('topic_', .SD[gamma == max(gamma)]$topic)), by = .(doc_id = document)]
dcast(merge(jobs, docs)[, .N, by = .(category, topic)], category ~ topic, value.var = 'N')
```

Good news about Craigslist dataset is that it has labels (category) for each job title, so you can build kind of confusion matrix which looks like that:

```
          category topic_1 topic_2 topic_3 topic_4 topic_5 topic_6
1:      accounting     357     113    1091     194     248     241
2:  administrative     595     216    1550     260     372     526
3: customerservice    1142     458     331     329     320     567
4:       education     296     263     251     280    1638     578
5:    foodbeverage     325     369     287    1578     209     431
6:           labor     546    1098     276     324     332     853
```

Of course, LDA is unsupervised and estimated topics shouldn't match original categories, but we observe semantic intersections between e.g. `labor` category and `topic_2`.